# How to get value of ViewData from one ActionResult to other ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ActionResult MyData(). In this I have a ViewData["test"] which gives me a boolean value. Now when redirected to another ActionResult MyData2(), the value is wiped out. **I can't use TempData due to some constraints.**

```
public ActionResult MyData()
{
    ViewData["test"] = ??? // returns true value after some calculations.                
}

public ActionResult MyData2()
{  
    ViewData["test"] //is coming null.                                  
}
```

Comment: use `Session["test"]`

Comment: `ViewData` is for passing data between a controller method and its view (it cannot be used for passing data between methods). You need to persist the data somewhere.

Comment: Using Session has it's own constraints, if thousands of users are logged in the same time every time a new session will be created, which needs to be kill or dispose. I don't want to do that. Could you please help me with a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `RedirectToAction` method with parameters:

```
public ActionResult MyData()
{
    var data = true;
    return RedirectToAction("MyData2", new { foo = data });
}

public ActionResult MyData2(bool foo)
{  
    var data = foo;
    return Content(data.ToString());
}
```